# how to prevent page from scrolling when loading new content to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one page website with navigation to anchors. Contetnt is loading dynamically when div is visible (when someone click on anchor or scrool to position on site). For example:

- anchor 1 > div1
- anchor 2 > div2
- anchor 3 > div3
- anchor 4 > div4

etc

But when you load page and click on anchor 3 it will take you there but then jump to div2 wchich has been loaded.

Is there any way to prevent it and bind vieport to show content of div4?

ThankS for any help!

Comment: Please provide a demo to understand the problem clearly

Comment: Here is page I'm working on: [link](http://przezkaerzet.pl/summer39.html)

Answer (score 0):

Give this on onclick event.

```
$('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: '100(PXValue)'
         }, 1000, 'linear');
```